# How to Import VM of Hyper-V on Compute Engine?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a Virtual Machine running in Hyper-V with Windows 2008 R2 Standard Edition, and I want to migrate the VM to Softlayer Cloud. I made an export of the virtual machine according to Microsoft documentation and I would like to do an import of this VM in Softlayer.

Is it possible? If yes, what is the processes to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upload the image to SoftLayer's object storage, and then you can import it inside the customer portal.

This link should provided the proper documentation on what exactly you need to do.

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/import-image

I hope that helps.